# How to check differences in bash and other shell profiles

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have some shell scripts which I run in my Linux/AIX machine with `bash` profile. Now my `bash` profile is going to be remove, and I will have `Korn shell (ksh)` or the `C shell (csh)`. How to verify whether my scripts will run fine in `Korn shell (ksh)` or `C shell (csh)`, even after `bash` shell is removed. Also, is there any differnce in commonly used commands between `bash` and `other (ksh, csh)`. Is there command to check, which shell is getting used while running the shell script.

Comment: Is `bash` being removed from the machine, or is the login shell just being changed to a different shell?

Comment: `bash` is going to remove from machine

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a problem, the default shell of your account is irrelevant. As long as bash is installed on the machine, you can use it to run your code. Either add a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Or, explicitly run the script with bash:

```
$ /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh
```

As for the differences, yes there are many. A script written for bash will not run in csh, their syntax is completely different. It *might* run on `ksh` but that will depend on your script. Not all features of the two shells are the same. For example:

```
$ cat test.sh
var="foo";
echo $var;

$ bash ./test.sh 
foo

$ ksh ./test.sh 
foo

$ csh ./test.sh 
var=foo: Command not found.
var: Undefined variable.
```

As you can see above, `var=foo` runs correctly in `ksh` (which is part of the bourne shell family) but fails for `csh`. Basically, think of each shell as its own programming language. You wouldn't expect the python interpreter to be able to run a perl program, why do you expect one shell to be able to run a script written for another?

Comment: It would be good to note, however, that between `ksh` and `bash` (not so much with the `csh` family of shells, though, as you have demonstrated), there is definitely the possibility of scripts that use restricted subsets of the shell features so that they could run under either.

Answer (score 0):

OP writes bash is going to be removed.
If you really cannot get bash installed. start each script with #!/bin/ksh and check for syntax problems:

```
ksh -n migrated_script
```

When you use bash/linux specific things you need to address them:
AIX will be "missing" flags on commands like find (changed last hour...) and ksh itself is also different.
Do not try csh, that is completely different.